# Binding to LDAP server works great with PHP CLI, but fails when tried via the web

Tags: php, ldap

I have a test page (PHP), that binds to an ldap server.  When I run
`php test.php`, everything works great.  It binds just fine.  However, when I go to http://my.domain.com/test.php, it won't bind at all.

I'm open to any suggestions that you might have.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The CLI configuration may not mirror the configuration used by your webserver - compare the output of `php -i` with a page calling `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on your webserver and update your configuration as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

We just had this problem happen. It turned out that all we had to do was restart Apache.

I have no idea what the cause was (I don't administer the server) but it was most likely security updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying this on Linux, make sure that selinux allows apache to open tcp connections. By default selinux is turned on and does not allow httpd to open tcp connections.